# SMBJ and DFS and "Nested Session"

Tags: java, smb, microsoft-distributed-file-system, smbj

I have a project, where I am given an id, and then using that ID look up files paths and process them... these files are on various mounted drives, so I am using the SMBJ java libraries to access them.

The problem I am having is that some (most) of the files are using a DFS mountpoint... Now, this in and of itself is NOT a problem per se, but apparently the SMBJ libraries appear to create nested sessions for each distinct DFS location.  So even though I am closing the actual FILE after I am done reading it the DiskSession object is holding onto all these nested sessions... and eventually either through the DFS config settings, or through these libraries I am hitting some point where it just blows up and stops allowing more sessions to be created.

I am processing hundreds of thousands of records, and the "crash" appears to happen somewhere around 500ish records(session) being processed.  I do not see anything obvious looking at the code to explicitly close these nested sessions.. in fact I see no external access to them at all externally from the DiskShare object.

Is there some sort of setting I am missing that maximizes the sessions that this is holding onto?  Other than me managing some sort of my own counter around this, and closing and reopening sessions/connections I am at a loss how to handle this.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Code below:

```
public class Smb {

private static SMBClient client;
private static String[] DFSMounts = {"DFS1","dfs1"};
private static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Smb.class);
private static HashMap<String,DiskShare> shares = new HashMap<>();
private static HashMap<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();
private static HashMap<Connection,Session> sessions = new HashMap<>();

private synchronized static SMBClient getClient(){
    if (client == null){
        SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().withDfsEnabled(true).build();
        client = new SMBClient(cfg);
    }
    return client;
}

private synchronized static Connection getConnection(String realDomainName) throws IOException{

    Log.info("DOMAIN NAME "+realDomainName);
    Connection connection = (connections.get(realDomainName) == null) ? client.connect(realDomainName) : connections.get(realDomainName);
    if(!connection.isConnected()) {
        connection.close();
        sessions.remove(connection);
        connection = client.connect(realDomainName);

    }
    // connection = client.connect(realDomainName);
    connections.put(realDomainName,connection);
    return connection;


}

private synchronized static Session getSession(Connection connection,SMBClient client){

    Session session = sessions.get(connection);
    if(session==null) {
        PropertiesCache props = PropertiesCache.getInstance();
        String sambaUsername = props.getProperty("smb.user");
        String sambaPass = props.getProperty("smb.password");
        String sambaDomain = props.getProperty("smb.domain");
        Log.info("CLIENT " + client);

        session = (sessions.get(connection) != null) ? sessions.get(connection) : connection.authenticate(new AuthenticationContext(sambaUsername, sambaPass.toCharArray(), sambaDomain));

        sessions.put(connection, session);
    }
    return session;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
public synchronized static DiskShare getShare(String domainName, String shareName) throws SmbException
{
    DiskShare share = shares.get(domainName+"/"+shareName);
    if((share!=null)&&(!share.isConnected())) share=null;
    if(share == null){
        try {


            PropertiesCache props = PropertiesCache.getInstance();
            String sambaUsername = props.getProperty("smb.user");
            String sambaPass = props.getProperty("smb.password");
            String sambaDomain = props.getProperty("smb.domain");
            String dfsIP = props.getProperty("smb.sambaIP");

            SMBClient client = getClient();

            String realDomainName = (Arrays.stream(DFSMounts).anyMatch(domainName::equals)) ? dfsIP: domainName;
            Connection connection = getConnection(realDomainName);
            Session session = getSession(connection,client);

            share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(shareName);
            shares.put(domainName+"/"+shareName,share);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.info("EXCEPTION E "+e);
            Log.info("EX "+e.getMessage());

            throw new SmbException();
        }

    }
    return(share);

}

public static String fixFilename(String filename){
    String[] parts = filename.split("\\\\");
    ArrayList<String> partsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parts));
    partsList.remove(0);
    partsList.remove(0);
    partsList.remove(0);
    partsList.remove(0);
    return String.join("/",partsList);

}


public static File open(String filename) throws SmbException {
    String[] parts = filename.split("\\\\");
    String domainName = parts[2];
    String shareName = parts[3];
    DiskShare share = getShare(domainName,shareName);
    Set<SMB2ShareAccess> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(SMB2ShareAccess.ALL.iterator().next());
    filename = fixFilename(filename);
    return(share.openFile(filename, EnumSet.of(AccessMask.GENERIC_READ), null, s,  SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN, null));
}
```

}

And here is how the OPEN is being used (to show it is closing the file after use):

```
String filename = documents.get(0).getUNCPath();
            try (File f = Smb.open(filename)){

               Process the file code...

                f.closeSilently();
            }
```

And:

```
    while(i.hasNext()){
        String filename =  (String)i.next();
        Log.info("FILENAME "+filename);
        try(File f = Smb.open(filename)){

           Process the file stuff here


        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing the exact error message. Furthermore SMBJ will do its own connection/session/share cacheing as long as you keep the client alive. There is no need to maintain your own maps.

Comment: That's fine, I only added the external caching because I was attempting to deal with the nested session problems.  Eventually the DFS Session appears to just die/close the connection after it has too many nested sessions... And all further requests to use the session on the connection, obviously fail because the connect was closed.

Comment: Hiery, Unfortunately with DFS it appears not to, the DFS Resolution appears to create new sessions, even if the mount point is somewhere it already has a connection/session for... I can reproduce this error consistently.  It appears that it creates a new Connection and session, even if the endpoint is resolved to something it already has,,, see trace below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a PR for SMBJ which changes this. It will reuse the nested session for same host. I have successfully used it myself to avoid the exact same problem you are having. https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/pull/489